# How to use the grid-list in Angular Material, so that all page content is displayed between the header and footer?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use Angular 6 and Material 6.4.7. I need to implement the grid-list on the main page. Make it so that the header and footer have a fixed width, and content occupies the rest of the space. How do I do this?

```
<mat-grid-list cols="1">
<mat-grid-tile-header>
    <app-header></app-header>
</mat-grid-tile-header>
<mat-grid-tile>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile-footer>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</mat-grid-tile-footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

**`MatGridList` is not a layout tool!** It is a *component* for displaying a list of tiles in a flexible grid format.

Based on your description, what you want to achieve is fairly easy with standard HTML and CSS flexbox. If you need more flexibility or a responsive layout, look into [Angular Flex-Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/README.md).