# What tools do you recommend using instead of mat-grid-list?

Tags: angular-material

I installed Angular Material to my project, and I really like it. However, working with the grid-list arose a lot of problems. Maybe there are some other tools that would help to simply work with grid?

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish by using mat-grid-list?

Comment: I'm trying to split the page into blocks, today I have a few questions that I have not been able to find answers to, and no one has yet responded to. So I thought about an alternative tool. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946166/how-to-make-a-list-of-cards-each-one-in-its-entire-width-using-a-grid-in-angul/52946574#52946574
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943177/how-to-use-the-grid-list-in-angular-material-so-that-all-page-content-is-displa

Comment: **`MatGridList` is not a layout tool!** It is a component for displaying a list of tiles. Look into Angular Flex-Layout as @p4r1's answer recommends.

Comment: i know this is an old post but i created a package called [ng-angular-grid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-angular-grid) to tackle this. May be useful for someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [@angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) for a way to structure your UI into a grid system that implements flexbox for a responsive layout of your pages.

Comment: For future reference, Angular Flex Layout is deprecated. I suggest you don't use it. https://medium.com/@caerus.karu/farewell-flex-layout-aaa567023769